# LED lights turning on/flickering when lights on another switch are on

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch

I know there are a number of other questions on similar topics, but I could use some more specific ideas on this case.

I've recently wired up 3 sets of recessed 9W LED lights in my basement, each on a smart dimmer switch (with neutral). There are 22 lights in total - 12 on one switch (main room), 6 on another (office), and 2 on the third (TV).

The wiring is as follows (all 14AWG NM Romex):

- Power comes from a 15A breaker into a large junction box (4x4x2.75") via a 2-wire cable
- From this box, power is split to 2 3-wire cables, each going to a dimmer, and an additional 2-wire cable
- The load wires from the switches then go out to the lights via a 2-wire cable each (powering the main room and TV lights)
- The additional 2-wire cable runs to another large junction box in the office, where it powers a 3-wire cable to the 3rd dimmer, which returns to heat 3 2-wire cables that split off to power office lights.

Here's a rough diagram. Solid lines are 2-wire, dashed lines are 3-wire (so load/lead actually run parallel to each other). Neutrals and grounds are all wired alongside.

[image: wiring diagram]

Now for the issue:

When the main room lights are turned on at the switch and the dimmer is set in the 30-70% range, the other lights often (but not always) turn on dimly (~50%) or start to brightly flicker. It seems to happen more reliably if the main room lights have been on for a while. The office lights exhibit this behavior more consistently than the TV lights. Usually, turning the main room dimmer all the way up or all the way down will cause the issue to disappear.

The office/TV lights work as expected if turned on by themselves.

Now, as I understand it, the issue of LEDs being powered by leaking current is not an uncommon one, as they require so little amperage to power. I'm aware of 2 common reasons:

1. The proximity of current in a wire is inducting current in others (namely, the 2-wire cables going to the lights, bypassing the switches)
2. The dimmers bleed enough current to power the lights

I hope #2 isn't the case, since the dimmers have neutral wires, and have hard-off states. All switches work as expected when the main room lights are off.

If it's #1, I'd imagine that this induction is occurring in the junction boxes. I could see this in the 1st box (as it's quite full), but the 2nd is just a few wires, and is only connected to the main room circuit in that it shares the same the source wire. I'm not sure how current from the main room could be inducting current in the office.

Unfortunately, at this point the ceiling is all patched up, so rewiring or installing new boxes is not going to be a small task. I'd like to find a way to resolve this with access only to the boxes, lights, and switches.

Any troubleshooting ideas are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: "smart dimmer switch (with neutral)" what is mean? the switching lane is neutral?

Comment: What make and model are the smart dimmers in question?

Comment: @xc source electronic switches require power to function in the past power was drawn through the load we could not see it with incandescent lamps. With LED lamps this small power draw caused the LED’s to glow or flicker so a new method of powering the switch was made called “neutral required” the switch is powered from line neutral and the national electric code started requiring a neutral at most switch locations to enable this. It’s not so much of a safety thing as a power saving method allowing LED’s to be used with electronic switches.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The dimmers are TreatLife WiFi Smart Dimmer Switch. Not a brand I've previously used before (presumably Chinese). I wouldn't be terribly surprised if they were the issue, but the behavior seems odd for it to be the switches.

Comment: @TFrazee -- yeah, your suspicions are correct in that they are pure Cheesium...